# How can relative paths in my C# class work with NUnit 3.x?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, relative-path

I have a C# class with the following code.

```
class Database
{
    private const string DatabaseFilepath = @"Settings\Database.xml";
    ...
    private void LoadDatabase()
    {
        XmlDocument databaseDocument = new XmlDocument();
        databaseDocument.Load(DatabaseFilepath);
    }
}
```

Now this code executes fine when I compile it, and it is able to read from the `Database.xml` file.  However, when I run a unit test that happens to execute this code using NUnit, I get the following exception.

> Result Message:   System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException : Could not find
>   a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\IDE\Settings\Database.xml'.

Now, when I was using Visual Studio Test Tools, this worked perfectly fine.  However, upon switching to NUnit, it looks like it is searching in a different working directory.  How can I change this?

Note: I have found other questions that ask how to use relative paths in **test** code.  In my example, my relative paths are are in my **class** code.

Comment: Which version of NUnit? There was a breaking change from NUnit 2.x to 3.x.

Comment: NUnit 3.x, sorry for not clarifying.  Will edit the post.

Comment: I find it ironic that you have unit tests for code that is not at all fit for production. First off, your path is hard coded, and the fact that it is relative to the **pwd** is even worse. If I ran your app from my home folder, I would have the same problem.

Comment: @MarioDS, what would you recommend then?  I understand why being relative to the **pwd** can be a problem, but what's wrong with the relative path being hard coded?

Comment: @ArKi Paths should, more often than not, be configurable. If this is a directory that is always lives in the folder of your `.exe` file, you *can* hard code it, but not relative to the pwd. Rather, at the moment you try to read the file, make sure you somehow know the root of your program / its installation directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a matter of policy, we decided that NUnit 3 should no longer change the current directory when running tests as it did in V2. With V2, you could run a whole list of assemblies in different locations and NUnit would change the cd to the location of each assembly before running it. We stopped because:

1. Changing the current directory is an unfriendly thing for a program that runs other programs to do.
2. It won't work anyway, since multiple assemblies located in different directories could be running in parallel at the same time.

There's an easy solution for test code, but you say this is code in your application under test so the solution is a bit different.

In the short term, your tests can set the CD before running the SUT code that requires it to be set a certain way. I recommend doing this in some level of SetUp and restoring it in the corresponding teardown.

In the longer term, fix your SUT so that it doesn't require the CD to be set in a particular way in order to run properly.

Comment: SUT == System Under Test.

Answer (score 12):

Charlie gave a great explanation for why they decided not to change the current directory.  For my code under test, I found using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` and combining it with my relative path using `Path.Combine(...)` to work fine for NUnit 3.x.

Comment: As with use of current directory, this will work fine so long as the base directory is the directory containing the relative path you need to access. That said, you have more control over that through NUnit command-line options or use of a test config file.